# How to pull keywords from an excel cell

Tags: excel, substring, keyword

I work in sourcing and I'm trying to look through a list of cells that contain part numbers and their description, but only pull the part number from the cell and place it in another column.

The part numbers have one of 10 possible prefixes (i.e. ABC, DDA, GHF, AH, etc.). The cells may look something like this:

- Tire Pressure ABC123873 Monitor
- Oil Life ABC849999999021 gauge
- Air conditioner GHF211 maintenance

And I want to be able to search that entire list and only pull the following information into another column:

- ABC123873
- ABC849999999021
- GHF211

As you can see from above, the challenge is that the part numbers are all different lengths and have no particular convention to them. The only thing you know about them is that they can have one of ten possible prefixes as I mentioned above (ABC, GHF, etc.).

The current solution I have looks something like this:

```
C2=FIND("ABC", A2)
D2=FIND(" ", A2, C2)
E2=MID(A2, C2, D2)
```

Where cell A2 contains the complete part number and description, C2 finds the beginning location of the part number by searching for its prefix, D2 finds the ending location of the part number by searching for a space, and then E2 pulls the substring between those two locations.

As you can see, this isn't a very robust solution and it only allows me to search for parts that start with ABC. I want to be able to search for all 10 possible prefixes (ABC, DDA, GHF, AH, etc.) but that does not work. I tried the approach below:

```
C2=FIND({"ABC", "DDA", "GHF", "AH"}, A2)
```

But that only searches for the ABC parts and disregards the other prefixes. Any help you all can offer will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it. I created a list of prefixes to search in column G. You could even put them on a separate page to keep it cleaner.

```
=MID(A1,FIND(G1:G2,A1,1),FIND(" ", A1, FIND(G1:G2, A1, 1))-FIND(G1:G2,A1,1))
```

I only tested two prefixes but just change `G1:G2` to `G1:G10` and put all you prefixes in them. The formula looks in A1. The first `FIND` finds the beginning character number. The rest of the equation is calculating the end of the product number minus the beginning which returns the amount of characters to return. Its important to know that `MID` isn't wanting the beginning and end character. It wants the beginning character and the number of characters after that to return. So `FIND(" ", FIND(G1:G2, A1, 1))` does not work as it returns too many characters. Give it a try.

Oh and don't forget to do `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to enter the array formula

The VBA answer would be

```
Sub findProductCode()

    ' Variable Declarations
    Dim productName As String
    Dim productArray() As String
    Dim wordCount As Integer

    ' Sets the active sheet to use
    ' Change Sheet1 to the name of your sheet
    With Sheets("Sheet1")

        ' Selects the first cell to check
        ' Change A1 to the first cell with data
        Range("A1").Select

        ' Loops through all rows until an empty row
        ' It will end if you have any empty rows in the midle of data
        Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

            ' Reads text out of the cell
            'Change A to the proper column
            productName = Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Text

            ' Splits the string into individual words
            productArray = Split(productName, " ")

            ' Loops through array to find the product number
            For wordCount = LBound(productArray) To UBound(productArray)

                ' Check if the word has the desired 10 prefixes
                ' Add more Or Left(productArray(wordCount), 3) = "xxx" until you have 10 of your prefixes you need
                If Left(productArray(wordCount), 3) = "ABC" Or Left(productArray(wordCount), 3) = "GHF" Then

                    ' Sends the product number to its cell
                    ' Change B to the correct destination Cell
                    Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = productArray(wordCount)
                End If
            Next

            ' Increments the active cell to the next cell down
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

If you don't know how, you need to enable the developer tab in excel. `File->Options->Customize Ribbon` Add the Developer to the Ribbon. The save your worksheet as `.xlsm` It is the macro enabled workbook. Then go to the developer tab, Choose "Visual Basic" and double click "ThisWorkBook". Paste the code in. You can run the code from there for a one time deal or you can create a button on the sheet that you can run this macro whenever you want.

To add a button, go back to the sheet you want the button on. On the developer tab select `Insert` and choose the first form control `Button`. Draw the button on your sheet and a dialog box will appear. select the `findProductCode` macro and select OK. Now every time you click the button it will run the macro.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely clarified a few things for me. Unfortunately it still does not search for all the prefixes. It only searches for the first prefix in the column G. For example, I have all 10 prefixes in column G, and all the part numbers + descriptions in column A. I entered this formula into column B, specifying the different prefixes (the first parameter in FIND) as G1:G10, The formula pulled down column B using autofill only pulled the part numbers starting with ABC (the prefix in G1). All part numbers with different prefixes returned #VALUE!. I'll edit the post with a screenshot.

Comment: Ugh, unfortunately Stack Overflow will not allow me to post a picture because I have a reputation of less than 10 since I just joined this site. Hopefully my description above made enough sense.

Comment: One more note: Instead of G1:G10, I typed in $G$1:$G$10 to make sure that autofill does not change the range as its dragged down (i.e. G2:G11 for the second row). I think the reason your formula may have worked is that autofill changed your range of prefixes to G2:G3 for the second row, and because this formula seems to only search for the first prefix in the G column, it made your trial a success.

Comment: You maybe right about the auto incrementing. I do see the problem and I am trying to find a new solution. Are you opposed to VBA? It can be solved easily with VBA.

Comment: I'm still unfamiliar with VBA, but if it solves the problem, I would gladly be willing to learn and apply it! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I added a VBA solution. I commented it rather well to explain what it is doing and what you need to change to your exact implementation. Check it out and please select my answer if it works for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the prettiest formula, but it should get you on your way.  There's definitely a VBA solution, if you're interested in a macro instead of a formula.

Assuming your `Tire Pressure ABC123873 Monitor` is in A1, enter this into B1:

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",";",1)," ","-",1),SEARCH("ABC",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",";",1)," ","-",1)),SEARCH(" ",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",";",1)," ","-",1))-SEARCH("ABC",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",";",1)," ","-",1)))
```

How it works, is it takes your A1, and first uses `Substitute`.  I substitute the first and second [space] for `;` and `-`. (Note, if there are more spaces than two, this will run into issues).  Then, I just use `Mid` to extract the part of the cell starting with `ABC` and going until it hits the space.  If you don't have "ABC" starting the values you want, you need to adjust the `Search("ABC"...` part (or use an array there).  I am still working on it, but hopefully this helps give an idea.